# How to forward file upload request to another domain in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, redirect, file-upload, request, form-data

How to forward the upload request to another domain?

UI will send upload request to

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/uploadFile \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 814459' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:4000' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F attachment1=@/C:/Users/superman/Desktop/tester.pdf
```

Need to attached 2 additional header and forward the request to

```
curl -X POST \
  http://anotherdomain.com/anotherUploadFile \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'newheader1: headervalue1' \
  -H 'newheader2: headervalue2' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 814459' \
  -H 'Host: anotherdomain.com' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F attachment1=@/C:/Users/superman/Desktop/tester.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will save image in first domain then you will initiate a new post request that will get that saved image and will forward to next domain like below. I am using 'request' npm package for it

```
 var options = { method: 'POST',
    url: server2 url,
    headers:
        { 
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' },
    formData:
        { 
            filename:
                { value: fs.createReadStream(req.file.path),
                    options: { filename: req.file.path, contentType: null } } } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);


});
```